# where does the assembler store constant .data? and how are they used?

Tags: assembly, mips

what where does the assembler store `somedata` in the following code? relative addressing? relative to what?

```
.data 
somedata: .word 0xDEADBEEF

.code
lw $s0 somedata
```

Comment: There is no such a thing as .code section. The .text section is for the executable instructions.

Comment: oops, yes. I recently converted from x86, still confused the two sometimes. thanks for the correction!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`somedata` is stored in the data segment, whose start address may vary with file format. Relative addressing is the [addressing mode](http://www.cs.umd.edu/class/sum2003/cmsc311/Notes/Mips/addr.html) for I-type (branch) instructions. Relative addressing and data declarations aren't related in any way.